# The weak-norm continuity of the map $u \mapsto y$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, continuity, weak-convergence

Consider $\Omega$ as a bounded interval of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $y\in L^{\infty}(\Omega \times (0,T))$ be a mild solution of the following parabolic partial differential equation:
\begin{equation}\label{e1}
 \begin{cases}
  \dot y(x,t)= y_{xx}(x,t)+ u(x,t)y(x,t) \quad 
  \text{in} \  \Omega \times (0,T),    \\
  y=0 \ \text{on} \     \Gamma \times (0,T), \\  y(0)=y_0 \ \text{in} \ \Omega
 \end{cases} 
\end{equation}
where $u\in L^2(\Omega \times (0,T))$ is a given function. The objective is to prove that the map $u \mapsto y$
is weak-norm continuous.

We consider a sequence of functions $u_n$ that weakly converges to $u^*$, and we let $y_n$ and $y^*$ be the solutions of the equation above corresponding to $u_n$ and $u^*$, respectively.

**My question is:**  How to demonstrate that $y^n$ converges to $y^*$ in the $L^2$ norm?